# Convert to LINQ of a foreach iteration gives compilation error in VS Asp.Net 2019 .Net 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq

I have a hierarical object (Result->userDataProfilePermissions->dataPermissions->Values->dataObjectValue)

I need to get distinct of dataObjectValue which is a string.

I've written the following loop, and it should work fine.

```cs
var businesses = new List<BusinessRbac>();
foreach (var udpp in result.userDataProfilePermissions)
{
    foreach (var dp in udpp.dataPermissions)
    {
        foreach (var v in dp.values)
        {
            if (!businesses.Any(x => x.BusinessName == v.dataObjectValue))
                businesses.Add(new BusinessRbac() { BusinessName = v.dataObjectValue, Regions = new List<RegionRbac>() });
        }
    }
}
```

When I convert it to LINQ, I get the following code

```cs
var businesses = (from udpp in result.userDataProfilePermissions
                  from dp in udpp.dataPermissions
                  from v in dp.values
                  where !businesses.Any(x => x.BusinessName == v.dataObjectValue)
                  select new BusinessRbac() { BusinessName = v.dataObjectValue, Regions = new List<RegionRbac>() }).ToList();
```

which is giving compilation error:

```
CS0841: Cannot user local variable 'businesses' before it is declared.
```

Comment: Seems you actually just want a groupby

Answer (score 4):

Your nested loop solution makes new insertions into `businesses` available for the uniqueness check during the following iteration, while your LINQ solution can't check `businesses` as it goes, because the result of the query has not been assigned.

You can fix this by performing uniqueness check in some other way - for example, by grouping on `dataObjectValue`, and selecting the first member of the group:

```
var businesses = result.userDataProfilePermissions
    .SelectMany(udpp => udpp.dataPermissions.SelectMany(dp => dp.values))
    .GroupBy(v => v.dataObjectValue)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Select(v => new BusinessRbac() {
        BusinessName = v.dataObjectValue,
        Regions = new List<RegionRbac>()
    }).ToList();
```